# reading directory path from properties file

Tags: java, file, properties

I need to know that how to read the directory path from a .properties file in java.
for example,

```
class clazz
{
string filename="d:/file.txt";
public void somemethod()
{
FileWriter f=new FileWriter(filename, true);
// etc
}
```

i want to read the filename from .properties file rather than from a variable.
how it can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A fairly simple way is to use a resource file, through the [`ResourceBundle`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html) class.

```
ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("com/file");
```

Where `com/file` is the **`file.properties`** in the `com` package.

This file could have a line like this:

```
file.name=C:\dir\file.txt
```

For get this particular data.

```
String filename = bundle.getString("file.name");
```

I hope this can help you. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [`Properties` class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) `load()` method.  It reads in a file (in the common properties format) and then you can query the value of a property based on its name

Comment: See also [*Properties*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/properties.html).

Answer (score 0):

If the properties file is in your class path then do this:

```
Properties prop = new Properties();
prop.load(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("file.txt"));
Sting fileName = prop.get("fileName");
```